# Sequential order for executing Lex and Yacc?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have heard my teachers say that Yacc file should be executed first because it creates yy.tab.h which will be used in Lex file or vice versa. I am really confused about it. I want to know what is the correct order for executing these two files?

Answer (score 1):

Yacc is the parser generator, you need it first. Then flex (the lexical analyser generator) must be executed to generate the lexical analyser that depends on the generated parser. So

1. Yacc
2. Flex

here an example: http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/lmcdowel/courses/si413/F10/labs/L04/calc1/ex1.html

Answer (score 0):

Lex is a lexer that converts strings like identifiers or reserved words or special characters into tokens, while yacc is a parser that can handle sequences of tokens (like IDENTIFIER EQUAL IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON). I'm not sure about the order of how to execute them at compile time, I suppose it makes no difference (you can just try it ;), however both must be run before the compiler is run.

Clearly, at runtime the code generated by lex runs before the code produced by yacc.